# Java Created Soap Client is not getting response but same is working from SOAPUI

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am creating a simple soap client payload in java but server replied that **"Server didn't recognize the value of http header"**. I copied the created soap payload and pasted in `SOAP-UI` and performed the request, the payload works perfectly.

I also double checked soap header information. Everything is correct. But still I am not getting response from my java client.

Can anyone provide me any idea on this?

```
public class SoapClientClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedOperationException, SOAPException, IOException, TransformerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Getting an instance of Soap Connection factory
    SOAPConnectionFactory myFct = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    //Getting a Soap Connection from the soap connection factory object
    SOAPConnection myCon = myFct.createConnection();
    //Getting a message factory object to create a message
    MessageFactory myMsgFct = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    //Using the message factory to create a message
    SOAPMessage message = myMsgFct.createMessage();
    //Adding message to the body

    SOAPPart mySPART = message.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope myEnvp = mySPART.getEnvelope();
    myEnvp.addNamespaceDeclaration("web","http://www.webservicex.net/");
    //SOAPHeader header = myEnvp.getHeader();
    //javax.xml.soap.Name HeaderName = myEnvp.createName("GetGeoIP", "web","http://www.webservicex.net/");
    //SOAPHeaderElement hltp = header.addHeaderElement(HeaderName);
    SOAPBody body = myEnvp.getBody();       
    javax.xml.soap.Name bodyName = myEnvp.createName("GetGeoIP", "web","http://www.webservicex.net/");                      
    SOAPBodyElement gltp = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);

    javax.xml.soap.Name myContent = myEnvp.createName("IPAddress","web", "http://www.webservicex.net/");        
    SOAPElement mySymbol = gltp.addChildElement(myContent);     
    mySymbol.addTextNode("192.128.62.43");              
    message.saveChanges();
    message.writeTo(System.out);
    URLEndpoint endPt = new URLEndpoint("http://www.webservicex.net//geoipservice.asmx");
    SOAPMessage reply = myCon.call(message, endPt); 
    //reply.writeTo(System.out);    
    System.out.println("\n");
    TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();

    Source sc = reply.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    tf.transform(sc, result);
    System.out.println("test");
    //conn.close();

    SOAPBody body1 = reply.getSOAPBody();
    if ( body1.hasFault() ) {
        SOAPFault newFault = body1.getFault();
        QName code = newFault.getFaultCodeAsQName();
        String string = newFault.getFaultString();
        String actor = newFault.getFaultActor();
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    myCon.close();
    //System.out.println(reply);            
}
```

Comment: Why not use jax-ws instead of building entire soap manually?

Comment: Payload is ok even it is implemented manually since this is tested in SOAP-ui.

Comment: Moreover, I am trying to connect to proxy server, server is not responding any data. I double checked EPR and other things.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old request but still answering if some one might run into similar issue. As per the error it is expecting HTTP header SOAPAction. Above code required two lines of HTTP header setting code.

```
SOAPEnvelope myEnvp = mySPART.getEnvelope();

MimeHeaders mheader=message.getMimeHeaders();
mheader.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP");

myEnvp.addNamespaceDeclaration("web","http://www.webservicex.net/");
```